# How to make Array paging with Laravel pagination?

Tags: laravel, pagination

```
$dataArray = inbox_table :: orderBy ('id', 'desc') -> get ();
```

I get all my data in the form and then to display what I have shown, 
$displayDataArray [] = $item in foreach; I throw it into it.
How do I paginate displayDataArray?

Answer (score 0):

```
$dataArray = inbox_table :: orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5)->toArray();
```

Comment: I also process the array and send it to view. This is not the case because I did not send the data to Array to view.

Comment: Where are we going to do paging?

Comment: foreach (dataArray as item) {
$ displayDataArray [] = $ item}
This is how I send the displayDataArray to the blade side. How do I do paging in displayDataArray?

Comment: $dataArray ['data'] pass blade side all data
-->
blade side=foreach($dataArray as $row){ $row->name}

Comment: But I have to send it as displayDataArray. I add the ones I want to check and send their references into displayDataArray. As a result, can't we do a paging in the array?